# How to get Geo Location Blazor Server

Tags: geolocation, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop

I am currently working on a blazor server project based on .NET 6. there is a requirement to get the geo location into the application. I have tried several ways but they don't work.is there anyone who knows about it ?? please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This shows how to call the browser API to get the current position.

`geoLocationJsInterop.js` (wwwroot\scripts)

```js
export function getCurrentPosition(dotNetHelper) {

    const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {

        const coord = {
            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
            accuracy: pos.coords.accuracy
        };

        dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnSuccessAsync', coord);
    }

    function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
}
```

`GeoLocation.razor`

```cs
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@implements IAsyncDisposable
<button @onclick=@GetLocationAsync>Get Location</button>

@if (geoCoordinates is not null)
{
    <div>
        Latitude : @geoCoordinates.Latitude <br />
        Longitude : @geoCoordinates.Longitude<br />
        Accuracy : @geoCoordinates.Accuracy
    </div>
}

@code {
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> moduleTask = default!;
    private readonly DotNetObjectReference<GeoLocation> dotNetObjectReference;
    private GeoCoordinates? geoCoordinates = null;

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime jsRuntime { get; set; } = default!;

    public GeoLocation()
    {
        moduleTask = new(() => jsRuntime!.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
            identifier: "import",
            args: "./_content/ChatClient.Core/scripts/geoLocationJsInterop.js")
        .AsTask());

        dotNetObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    }

    public async Task GetLocationAsync()
    {
        var module = await moduleTask.Value;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "getCurrentPosition", dotNetObjectReference);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task OnSuccessAsync(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates)
    {
        this.geoCoordinates = geoCoordinates;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    public class GeoCoordinates
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Accuracy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note: Change the path of the `.js` file to suite your project. In this case I was referencing a RCL called `ChatClient.Core`.

`args: "./scripts/geoLocationJsInterop.js"` for your root project.

This component runs on either wasm or blazor-server.

[API Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)